# Show full content of related entity using Entity Reference in node view

Tags: views, entities

Basically I've created a relationship between two content types: Testimonials and Case Study as follow: in Case Study I've created a field *Testimonial* using the Entity Reference widget.

When I create a *case study* type of content I can choose a *Testimonial* to link with this case study. So far so good.

My question is this: When I view the newly created Case Study content, I can only see the title of testimonial but none of the additional field available in the testimonial content type.

In order to view the full content, do I need to create a View for it or is there a way to display the full content as it is?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a view for this. Instead, you can set the display settings for your entity reference field to *Full display*.

On *Structure > Content types > My content type > Manage display*, for the entity reference field choose *Rendered entity* as format. You can then have *Full content* as a view mode.

> [image]